# WebAssembly.Compile is disallowed on the main thread, if the buffer size is larger than 4KB

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I'm trying out a simple hello world WebAssembly example and I'm having trouble understanding an error I'm seeing in Chrome 59:

> RangeError: WebAssembly.Compile is disallowed on the main thread, if the buffer size is larger than 4KB. Use WebAssembly.compile, or compile on a worker thread.

```
src/wasm/counter.wasm:13
  10 | let wa;
  11 | const make = source => {
  12 |   // buffer should already be set
> 13 |   return wa = new Module(buffer);
  14 | };
  15 | 
  16 | const WebAssemblyModule = function(deps = {
```

I've followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://blog.openbloc.fr/webassembly-first-steps/), and I can build everything without error. I'm using `create-react-app` [rewired with `wasm-loader`](https://github.com/ballercat/wasm-loader/issues/3).

If I'm using my local build of the counter module I get the error I mentioned in the beginning. If I try and use a pre-built version (for example the one [in this project](https://github.com/jaydson/wasm-test)) it works fine.

When I build my module, I'm using the same command as specified in the tutorial. The project with the working module has the same command listed in its README:

```
emcc counter.c -O1 -o counter.wasm -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1
```

Any idea what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some browsers limit the size of modules that can be compiled synchronously because that blocks the main thread. As the error message says, they'd rather have you use `WebAssembly.compile` which returns a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I'd advise you to go further and use `WebAssembly.instantiate` which will both compile and instantiate asynchronously and, in some cases, generate higher performance code. See [its documentation](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#webassemblyinstantiate), the signature is:

```
Promise<WebAssemblyInstantiatedSource>
  instantiate(BufferSource bytes [, importObject])
```

`bytes` is the same buffer you were passing to `Module` above, and `importObject` is the same thing you'd have passed to `Instance`.

---

Another option is to make your `.wasm` file smaller. That's pretty brittle because the main-thread size limit is arbitrary and you're not really in control of your generated code's size. You could try compiling with `-O2` or `-Os`, and you can run [binaryen](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen)'s optimizer to try to reduce size. You could also split your code into multiple smaller modules, compile each individually, and then dynamically link them together (share import / export, and use the same memory for all of them).

But again, that's not really something you should rely on, and you're still blocking the main thread.

---

Yet another option is to move all your code to a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). You can block them as much as you want, no need for `Promise`s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This makes sense - the problem seems to come from `wasm-loader` as it's the one doing the module loading. I've submitted an issue there: https://github.com/ballercat/wasm-loader/issues/4

Comment: Could you give more details, when sync module compile creates more slow code?

Comment: @Vitaly the main difference is whether the compiler knows about the memory that was allocated or not: if a ~4GiB virtual reservation was possible and signal handlers were installed then no explicit bounds checks are needed. That's not necessarily known at compile time, but is definitely known at instantiation time.

Comment: @JFBastien i still don't understand how this can be related to sync/async compile. From my noob's point of view, the only difference of async compile is moving code to separate thread, to not freeze main one. May be you could link to some articles with details, why sync WA init can produce less optimal code?

Comment: It's not about sync versus async, it's about compiling with a known `importObject`, which is only provided at instantiation time. If the implementation actually compiles at compile time, instead of delaying to first instance, and has different memory types, then it could be forced to recompile on instantiate. The memory kind (~4GiB allocation, with signal handler installed) is what allows faster code, without it you have to generate explicit bounds checks. As a reference, look at [mentions of fast memory](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/JavaScriptCore/wasm/WasmMemory.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Create a URL object by Buffer, then use instantiateStreaming async method to load wasm.

```
const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "application/wasm" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
wasm = await instantiateStreaming(fetch(url), {});
```